# Which Windows remote desktop software can mount remote drive as local drive?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, mount, remote-access

Almost every remote desktop software has a file transfer mode where one can send/receive files between local and remote machine in their GUI, but I wonder which software can simply mount a remote drive as local drive so that I can use a file manager of my choice, not their GUI?

I know this can be done (albeit with an extra manual step) in Windows Remote Desktop Connection, but this is not an option in my case as I need to do it over WAN without re-configuring the router port forwarding. Also, VPN is not currently an option. So I need something like RustDesk, but with ability to mount remote drives.

FOSS options are preferred.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [softwarerecs.se],  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).